# Weird error Java Hashmap types Long, String

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a very weird behavior in a Java program. I have a Long, Long hashmap, retrieved from a method but when I tried to get the information from it, this hashmap is a String, String without any errors nor warnings.. Below my code:

```
List<HashMap<Long, Long>> getAggregateResult(String idCheptel, Integer limit) {
    StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
    hql.append("select new map(t.prod.id, count(t.prod.id))");
    ... //rest of implem.
    return entityManager.createQuery(hql.toString()).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();
}
```

**Call of the function**

```
... //in other method try to retrieve the information
    for (HashMap<Long, Long> map : getAggregateResultVetProduct(idCheptel, limit)) {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>" + map.get(0L)); //always null
            //the map is asked in Long, but in debugger it's a String, String
            for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey()); //here key are 0
                System.out.println("Value: " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
```

If someone could give me some information why there is this behavior.  Thanks.

**Edit**

Here some information:
I am using Intellij. And below the screen shot of the debugger, since it was asked.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the debugger output or screen shot that you refer to?

Comment: What does the method getAggregateResultVetProduct do ?

Comment: Also entityManager.createQuery doesn't return a HashMap I guess.

Comment: Can you use bigger LOng's for the key?  I think small Long's are stored as byte (aka char).

Comment: Somewhere along the implementation of `getResultList` there is probably something that creates a raw map and/or suppresses unsafe warnings.

Comment: "here key are 0" No, according to the debugger screenshot, the key is `"0"` - it's a string. Try adding `Long key = entry.getKey();` in the inner loop, and you'll get a `ClassCastException`. (On the other hand, `Long value = entry.getValue();` will be OK).

Answer (score 0):

Information about generics are erased during compilation. So during the runtime your method returns just `HashMap`. So the interesting question is what is real type of the return value of `.getResultList()` method.